# An issue with common prefix list function

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, logic, racket

```
(define (long a b)
(cond ((null? a) '())
      ((null? b) '())
      (else
(if (equal? (car a) (car b))
    (cons a (long (cdr a) (cdr b)))
    (cons b (long (cdr a) (cdr b)))))))
```

This function is suppose to the find the longest common prefix between 2 lists. So when I input '(1 2) and '(1 2 3), I should get '(1 2). However, when I run (long '(1 2) '(1 2 3)), I get ((1 2) (2)). When I retraced my steps through my code, I don't seem to find the issue. Can someone please help me find the issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is the following:

```
(define (long a b)
  (cond ((null? a) '())
        ((null? b) '())
        ((equal? (car a) (car b)) (cons (car a) (long (cdr a) (cdr b))))
        (else '())))
```

When a list terminates the prefix is the empty list; if both the `car`s are equal, the result is the list with the car and the longest prefix of the `cdr`s of the lists. Otherwise, the lists differ for the first element, so the result is the empty list.

Answer (score 0):

One can use 'for/list' loop with conditions here:

```
(define (long a b)
  (for/list ((i a)
             (j b)
             #:break (not(= i j)))
    i))

(long '(1 2 3) '(1 2))
```

Output:

```
'(1 2)
```